# Is \hl incompatible with \textquotesingle? ("Cannot use \XeTeXglyph with ectt1000; not a native platform font")

Tags: xetex, packages

The command `\hl{\textquotesingle{}test\textquotesingle{}}` (where `\hl` is from the [soul](https://ctan.org/pkg/soul) package) yields the following error:

```
Cannot use \XeTeXglyph with ectt1000; not a native platform font.
\remove@tlig #1->\XeTeXglyph
```

I am using Windows 10 and:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 \write18 enabled.
```

This did work in a different setup a while ago. I think I used `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex` back then. (And no, I cannot use `pdflatex` this time, unfortunately.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: don't show only some snippets, make a small but complete example that can be used for test.

Comment: I don't think `soul` plays well with `xetex`. On CTAN there is a package `xesoul` (but I've got no experience with it).

Comment: @campa Thank you! After failing to use it, I ended up Copy+Pasting the few lines of `xesoul` and started experimenting with it. It has the assumption for your system to have the `FreeMono` font. It does not find that font, even if I provide it manually. Says: `Font \SOUL=@tt=[./FreeMono.ttf] not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or installed font not found.` Now this becomes a separate issue, but it is at the core of the original problem: as per their own documentation, `soul` uses the (seemingly incompatible?) `ectt1000` font, which I am now trying to replace and failing to do so

Comment: Funnily enough, `\setmonofont{FreeMono}` works just fine

Comment: that is the problem if you show only snippets: nobody knows what you are exactly doing and why it fails for you (I can guess but I would prefer to see the code to confirm if my hunch is right).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The `\SOUL=@tt...` part comes straight from the [xesoul.pdf](https://ftp.ntou.edu.tw/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/xesoul/xesoul.pdf). Sorry about not providing a full replication (I guess, I have not spent enough time to produce a minimal reproducible sample in Latex yet). I shall do it next time! Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: I decided to take the ugly way out, and just get rid of `soul` (I don't want to get a degree in `fonts-in-latex` just to be able to just change a font; it is just frustrating)

Comment: You probably forgot the \makeatletter before the copied code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments by campa:

The problem stems from the fact that the `soul` package is not playing nicely with `XeLaTeX`. As [the `soul` package's documentation](https://ftp.ntou.edu.tw/ctan/macros/generic/soul/soul.pdf), it uses the font `ectt1000` by default, which (apparently) `xelatex` has trouble with.

After failing to change the font (by Copy+Pasting the `xesoul` package from [here](https://ftp.ntou.edu.tw/ctan/macros/xetex/latex/xesoul/xesoul.pdf) and playing around with that) I found the easiest solution was simply to replace `soul`.

### Before

I only used it for `\hl`, like so:

```tex
\sethlcolor{X}
% ...
\hl{Y}
```

### After

This can be easily replaced with `\colorbox{X}{Y}` (from the [xcolor](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor?lang=en) package) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the font soul uses to measure the content to an unicode font. You can do it e.g. like this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\RequirePackage{soul}
\makeatletter 
\setbox\z@\hbox{\ttfamily\global\let\SOUL@tt\ttfamily}
\setbox\z@\hbox{\SOUL@tt-}
\SOUL@ttwidth\wd\z@
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hl{\textquotesingle{}test\textquotesingle{}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am getting `Package soul: Reconstruction failed.` but I'm sure it has to do with some other issues I introduced

Comment: did you try exactly my example or did you add unrelated stuff?

Comment: I added your example to my mess of a code (because that's where the problem is that I'm trying to solve). I know, you want me to provide a complete example, but unless you are really curious and ask me to do so, I'd rather not spend the time -- especially since I already fixed it with (i) my ugly hackfix, and also (ii) your other solution of adopting the `xesoul` code, after moving it to behind `\makeatletter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{book}

\RequirePackage{soul}
\makeatletter 
\setbox\z@\hbox{\ttfamily\global\let\SOUL@tt\ttfamily}
\setbox\z@\hbox{\SOUL@tt-}
\SOUL@ttwidth\wd\z@
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\hl{\textquotesingle{}test\textquotesingle{}}

\end{document}
```

This should resolve it.

Comment: Welcome! This seems a straight copy from another answer, though.